# Copying the values from specific columns from an SQL table to another table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two Tables: Users and Permission. They share 2 columns with the same name, so I need to copy values of those 2 columns from 'Users' to 'Permission'. However, **since there is a third column on Permission that cannot go blank, it needs to be filled with the value '0' by default**.

See the diagram for further understanding:
[image]

What SQL command should I use to perform this feat?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
insert into permission( userid, login, permission )
select UserId, login, 0 from users
```